# Microsoft Xbox 360 pad and Kodi mapping issues - Retropie 4.0

Tags: retropie, gamepad

I installed Retropie 4.0 on a Raspberry 3 and everything went really smooth.
Being the Media Center a core part of the plan I installed Kodi from optional repos, no problem at all.

Everything nice once again except the fact that in Kodi pads are completely wild (right goes down, left goes up).

Therefore I think I need to change something with its mapping.

As far as I've understood if I use:
cat /proc/bus/input/devices

I should find my pad / joystick name:
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=045e Product=0719 Version=0100
N: Name="Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver"

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=045e Product=0719 Version=0100
N: Name="Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver"

The next and final step is not entirely clear...

I think I need to find a good xml and paste it with the correct name found above in the right folder.

I have tried but the pad is still acting "crazy":

  
    
      Controller (PittoruleXBOX 360)
      Select
      Back
      FullScreen
      ContextMenu

What am I doing wrong?
I'd expect the pad to stop going in one direction automatically, at least...

Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 2):

I have a work in progress fix for this!

Make sure to backup /usr/share/kodi/system/keymaps/joystick.Microsoft.Xbox.360.Controller.xml

then put this file in /usr/share/kodi/system/keymaps/ with the name joystick.Microsoft.Xbox.360.Controller.xml

download from here:
http://pastebin.com/8EdGdawL

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue as you.  I've re-mapped with a correct joystick.xml file with the same symptoms.

I had to change the settings in KODI to disable the controller input.  I use the Yatse Android app to control KODI now.  I would like to see a resolution to this issue too.

Thanks for posting.

Comment: This should rather be a comment than an answer to my question :)

Please keep it in mind or you will get downvotes.

Comment: Thanks...Won't let me comment.  I have to have >50 reps.